# XSLT 1.0 - Remove Duplicate Nodes From Variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've seen many posts on this, but none of them have helped me figure out my problem.

Test1.xml

```
<table>
    <row>
        <col1>A</col1>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>B</col1>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>C</col1>
    </row>
</table>
```

Test2.xml

```
<table>
    <row>
        <col1>A</col1>
        <col2>ABC</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>B</col1>
        <col2>ABC</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>A</col1>
        <col2>ABC</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>C</col1>
        <col2>ABC</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>A</col1>
        <col2>DEF</col2>
    </row>

</table>
```

Test.xsl (XSLT 1.0)

```
<xsl:variable name="input" select="document('test1.xml')/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$input" mode="special"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@" mode="special">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@" mode="special"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row" mode="special">
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="document('test2.xml')/Table/Row[current()/Col1 = Col1]/Col2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="unique_cols" select="$cols[not(. =  preceding-sibling::*)]"/>

    <!-- Debug -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$unique_cols">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    ----
</xsl:template>
```

Expected Output:

```
<col2>ABC</col2>
<col2>DEF</col2>
----
<col2>ABC</col2>
----
<col2>ABC</col2>
```

Current Output:

```
<col2>ABC</col2>
<col2>ABC</col2>
<col2>DEF</col2>
----
<col2>ABC</col2>
----
<col2>ABC</col2>
```

The col2 values in $unique_cols should be distinct per col1 values.  If unique col2 values could be selected in $cols, even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured this out based on an answer provided on another post (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/microsoft.public.xsl/i8FwJUD0r8U).

```
<xsl:variable name="cols" select=
   "document('test2.xml')/table/row[current()/col1 = col1]/col2[not(. = ../preceding-sibling::*/col2[current()/col1 = ../col1])]"/>
```

This appears to select unique col2 values into $cols eliminating the need for the second variable.

Comment: It'd still be nice to know how to get it to work with the second variable (i.e., keep the select for $cols the same as in the question and then select the unique values out of $cols into $unique_cols). Please provide an answer if you know how to get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace**:

```
    <xsl:variable name="unique_cols" select="$cols[not(. =  preceding-sibling::*)]"/>
```

**with**:

```
    <xsl:variable name="unique_cols" select=
         "$cols[not(../col1 =  ../preceding-sibling::*/col1)]"/>
```

**The full transformation (initially corrrected to fix a multitude of lexical errors) now becomes (also using my own file-Uris):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="input" select=
      "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/test1.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$input" mode="special"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="special">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="special"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="special">
        <xsl:variable name="cols" select=
        "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/test2.xml')
             /table
               /row[current()/col1 = col1]
                 /col2"/>
        <xsl:variable name="unique_cols" select=
             "$cols[not(../col1 =  ../preceding-sibling::*/col1)]"/>

        <!-- Debug -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$unique_cols">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        ----
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the files are:

c:/temp/delete/test1.xml:

```
<table>
    <row>
        <col1>A</col1>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>B</col1>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>C</col1>
    </row>
</table>
```

and: c:/temp/delete/test2.xml:

```
<table>
    <row>
        <col1>A</col1>
        <col2>ABC</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>B</col1>
        <col2>ABC</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>A</col1>
        <col2>ABC</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>C</col1>
        <col2>ABC</col2>
    </row>
</table>
```

**When the transformation is performed on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<table>

   <col2>ABC</col2>
        ----

    <col2>ABC</col2>
        ----

    <col2>ABC</col2>
        ----

</table>
```

Comment: This is not a correct solution. If test2.xml had another row where col1 = A and col2 = DEF, unique_cols would not include it.

Comment: I realize I was not very clear in what I was asking for in this post. File2.xml can have several entries where col1 values are equal and col2 have same or different values (e.g., col1 = A, col2 = ABC; col1 = A, col2 = ABC; col1 = A, col2 = DEF;). For this example, the transformed XML should have the following where col1 = A: <col2>ABC</col2> <col2>DEF</col2>.

Comment: @RyanFlynn, Then, please, edit the question and explain well. It would be good to provide a more representative example.

Comment: I made changes to the question to hopefully clarify what I'm after.